# Dell PowerEdge t610 will not boot ESXI installer from USB

Tags: vmware-esxi, boot, dell-poweredge, usb-boot

I downloaded the ESXI installer from VMWare for V8.

I checked and the MD5 matches with what's listed on the download.

I'm using a Mac to write the iso to a known working USB (using DD)

The server will not boot in uefi or bios mode from the USB - I get the message no bootable disk found.

I have an Ubuntu ISO and if I use the **same** dd command to send it to the **same** USB device it boots on the server. This rules out the dd command being the problem, and rules out the USB device being a problem.

Why won't the esxi v8 iso not boot? I can't figure it out.

EDIT - I just created a VirtualBox vm and booted from the iso attached to the virtual CD and it booted the installer, so the image is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a test try using iDRAC virtual console to mount the .iso installer file remotely - that'll help diagnose if this is a USB-specific problem or something else with the server.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the iso image from VMWare does not create a partition table and so the iso by default is not bootable.

What I had to do was format a partition as FAT (Not EXFAT or that BS that the mac provides) and `rsync` the contents of the iso image to the FAT partition (rather than DD the whole drive image).

Then it boots.

Won't install, but that's a hardware issue on my end but I fixed this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the t610 has a size limit on the usb drive. Yry a smaller drivee. 2gb. Or try reformatting to fat32

Comment: What about the fact that Ubuntu boots fine from the same USB drive?

Comment: Also, formatting does not really make sense if I'm using dd to write an iso image to the device, I don't think.

Comment: Try using Rufus instead of dd in cli